# Passing a variable between 2 actionscript3 files (.as)

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I pass a variable between 2 actionscript3 files (.as) ?

I have a main fla file and 3 as files, with a class each one...
I have a basic knownelge in AS2 but not too much in AS3

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are these classes, or just inline script held in external files?  You will need to post a much fuller question with some example code to get proper help.

Comment: Yes, they are classes, thanks for help. I modify my question ;)

Comment: Ok, that's a start.  Now, how are you instantiating those classes?  Where does the data that you want to pass originate?  Is one of these classes your Document Class?

Comment: The origin of the variable is each one of the external as files; They have approximately the same content, but they have a different variable that I want to pass to each one of the other files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to access some variables from anywhere in Flash. One way is to create some class with static methods and variables. For example:

```
package somenamespace {

    class Registry {

        static private var something_:String;

        public function get something():String {
            return something_;
        }


        public function set something(v:String):void {
            if (something_ === v) return;
            something_ = v;
        }

    }

}
```

Then you can access this variable from anywhere in Flash:

```
Registry.something = "example";
```

Comment: When my variable is in a private function, how can I get it in another as file ?

Comment: In that case, you need to create a getter/setter function. That would be the proper way to access variables anyway.

Comment: Have you an example of code how to do that ? It would be very helpful for me :)

Comment: @BizBoss, I've added an example with getter/setter.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to pass data between classes is to pass it by reference.  This is better than maintaining data with global scope as it permits you to decouple your classes.

It's hard to give you specific advice without seeing your classes and the data you are trying to pass, but here's a simple example using a document class (Main.as) and a child class (Child.as):

Main.as:

```
package {
    class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var someData:String;
        //constructor
        function Main()
        {
            //create the data
            someData = "my string";

            //create an instance of child
            var child:Child = new Child(someData);
        }
    }
}
```

Child.as:

```
package {
    class Child
    {
        private var someData:String;
        //constructor
        function Child(initData:String)
        {
            someData = initData;
            trace(someData); // my string
        }
    }
}
```

It sounds like in your case you need a controller class to instantiate the classes you have and to manage the relationships between them.  This would be a variation of the Main class above, instantiating all three classes and extracting and passing around their data.